# Why is GVim displaying the output from system() function as ^M and ^@

Tags: command-line, gvim

```
function! g:insert_date()

    let l:pattern="\\d\\{2}:\\d\\{2}"

    let l:match=match(getline('.'),l:pattern)

    let l:curline=getline('.')

    echo "Current line: ". l:curline

    normal gg

    let l:time=system("time /t")

    let l:date=system("date /t")

    let l:date_time=l:date."\t".l:time

    if l:match!=-1

        echo match

        normal dd

        "call setline('.',system('time /t')."<<>>")

        call setline('.',l:date_time)

    else

        echo match ." ". l:curline." ".l:pattern

        sleep 2

        normal O

        "call setline('.',system("time /t")."\r")

        call setline('.',l:date_time)

        normal dd

    endif

endfunction
```

I have this code above that is supposed to insert the date and time
 in the first line of the file.

I was going to assign it to a BufRead autocommand but it's not perfect, yet.  Basically, it checks if there is a time string in the first line of the file and if found it updates it. If not, it opens a newline above and inserts the date. The problem is that it does not open a newline when the string is not
found. `normal 0` is the culprit. It works when I type it in the command line but fails when the function is called. Also, I don't why you have to escape the regExp twice in the script while it works fine with
one backslash with `?` and `/`. 
As you can see, I have commented the line with the `system()` function because it keeps inserting visible null bytes(ascii 0) and carriage returns(ascii 13). What is `system()` doing that makes them visible. I haven't found a workaround for this( `read!` does not store in a variable. I need the date and time in 
one line).

```
call setline('.',system("time /t")."\r")

call setline('.',system("time /t")."\n\n\n\n\n")  ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@

call setline('.',system("time /t")."\n\n\n\n\n")  ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ (0)

call setline('.',system('time /t')."\r\r\r\r\r\r") ^M^M^M^M (13)

read! time\ /t
```

**Additional details:**

1. encoding=utf-8
2. `set list` is off
3. Font is consolas:h10
4. file format is dos
5. version=7.3

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. The `system` function reads from the windows `date` function into the file. The `date` function outputs text with `CRLF` as its ending while the file had `LF` line endings. Vim spots the difference and displays it. I replaced all the line endings to `CRLF` and they disappeared.